# Trying code for an array based stack out of a textbook. Am I missing something?

Tags: c++

This is the code as it appears from textbook. It looks complete to me but I keep getting errors that say " 'AStack' : class has no constructors " and " 'AStack' : use of class template requires template argument list    ".

```
template <typename E> class Stack {
private:
   void operator =(const Stack&) {} // Protect assignment
   Stack(const Stack&) {} // Protect copy constructor

public:
   Stack() {} // Default constructor
   virtual ~Stack() {} // Base destructor

   // Reinitialize the stack. The user is responsible for
   // reclaiming the storage used by the stack elements.
   virtual void clear() = 0;

   // Push an element onto the top of the stack.
   // it: The element being pushed onto the stack.
   virtual void push(const E& it) = 0;

   // Remove the element at the top of the stack.
   // Return: The element at the top of the stack.
   virtual E pop() = 0;

   // Return: A copy of the top element.
   virtual const E& topValue() const = 0;

   // Return: The number of elements in the stack.
   virtual int length() const = 0;
};



template <typename E> class AStack: public Stack<E> {
private:
   int maxSize; // Maximum size of stack
   int top; // Index for top element
   E *listArray; // Array holding stack elements

public:
   AStack(int size =defaultSize) // Constructor
      { maxSize = size; top = 0; listArray = new E[size]; }

   ~AStack() { delete [] listArray; } // Destructor

   void clear() { top = 0; } // Reinitialize

   void push(const E& it) { // Put "it" on stack
      Assert(top != maxSize, "Stack is full");
      listArray[top++] = it;
   }

   E pop() { // Pop top element
      Assert(top != 0, "Stack is empty");
      return listArray[--top];
   }

   const E& topValue() const { // Return top element
      Assert(top != 0, "Stack is empty");
      return listArray[top-1];
   }

   int length() const { return top; } // Return length
};
```

Comment: Show us [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (user code). Add error messages verbatim, marking lines where they point to in the code.

Comment: Looks like an error occurs in class client code. How do you use it?

Comment: You use `defaultSize` and `Assert` which are not defined

Comment: It looks like you tried to declare `AStack name;` and need to read some more about templates before using them.